# Node.js/NPM and Juggernaut Install on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, windows-7, npm, juggernaut

I've edited my original question after discovering perhaps the root of my problem (Juggernaut is not working in my Rails app, regardless of the Juggernaut gem and Redis-server working OK):

After looking at the Chrome's Javascript console, I've discovered that the error may be completely due to the failure to locate Juggernaut. It reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Juggernaut is not defined
```

This leads me to believe there is a problem with Node.js and Juggernaut. I have both, but when I try to install Juggernaut through NPM (`npm install juggernaut -g`) I get:

> npm ERR! cb() never called
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm not ok

But I noticed it did put Juggernaut into my `C:\nodejs\` folder, under the sub-directory `C:\nodejs\node_modules`

So my main question, I believe is: how do you get NPM, Node.JS and Juggernaut to play nice on Windows?

Comment: You can't install NPM on windows